Gatsby seems not fetching certain fields
Gatsby start fetching certain fields when you deep populate query in the gatsby-config like this
{
      resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
      options: {
        apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL || "http://127.0.0.1:1337",
        accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
        collectionTypes: [
          {
            singularName: "article",
            queryParams: {
              publicationState:
                process.env.GATSBY_IS_PREVIEW === "true" ? "preview" : "live",
              populate: {
                cover: "*",
                blocks: {
                  populate: "*",
                },
                author: "*",
                category: "*",
                ending: "*",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            singularName: "author",
          },
          {
            singularName: "page",
            queryParams: {
              publicationState:
                process.env.GATSBY_IS_PREVIEW === "true" ? "preview" : "live",
              populate: {
                sections: {
                  populate: "*",
                },
              },
            },
          },

though I have problem with fetching so-called dynamic zones like sections, which are here
populate: {
                sections: {
                  populate: "*",
                },
              },

I suppose I need to deep query these sections that I need, but whenever I add smth in this part, build fails(
I tried configuring gatsby-node with customizingSchema, which also throws a build error and of course various methods how I could deep populate query in gatsby-source-strapi. Any ideas?
